# Declare a struct during execution?

Tags: qt, data-structures, struct, runtime

Let's say I'm reading a table from a file but the set of columns isn't defined in principle (they are defined in the first line of the file). I'm thinking to make a list of objects read from the file. The first line has the titles and in the following lines each line has the object values. Each object might be a struct but in this case I'll have to define the structure fields (the column names) in execution time.

How to approach this issue?

I'm using Qt. Clever approaches then mine (described above) are welcome.

Exemple, table names:

```
FirstName LastName
sdasdc    bdfgdg
drtggw    nhnfgh
wrew      rtyhrt
```

Comment: Read about `QVariant` as a container for many kinds of values and about `QVector` as an array of these values. May be you will use `QMap` (in this case you will have names of the fields of that structure).

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data in the `QMap<QString, QVariant>` (`QVariant` acts like a union for the most common Qt data types). So, it will be easy for you to name each field of your structures, and to get an access to the data by name (not by index).

Also you can just use `QList<QVariant>`. It sounds a little simpler, but in this case you will use indices for getting values from this "structure" (so the code will be not so clear), so I'd recommend you to use `QMap`.

**Update:**

So, `QMap<QString, QVariant>` or `QList<QVariant>` is an item in the list. Since you need to have a list of such items, you will use `QList<QMap<QString, QVariant>>` or `QList<QList<QVariant>>`.

Let's compare these options:

If you have very small list (like in your example - only three items), it will be ok to use `QList<QMap<QString, QVariant>>`. In this case there will be three copyes of each title of each column. But it will be easy to get any information about any item.

If you need to process very big lists, it is much more effective to use `QList<QList<QVariant>>`. In this case you'll put titles of the columns in the first element of the list, and the rows with data into next items of this list. It is more effective (you spend less memory), but a little more complex to process.

Comment: You mean, for each column, turn each line in a `QMap<QString, QVariant>`? And then to make a `QList<QMap>`? I would like to have a `QList<Something>` in which something is a structure whose members are the column titles.

Comment: @KcFnMi the answer is updated. The idea was to turn each row into `QMap<QString, QVariant>` (where `QString` is a name of each column, and `QVariant` is a data from this column and this row). So, "something" is `QMap<QString, QVariant>` or `QList<QVariant>`.